# Using /usr/bin/env to change directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I want to automatically execute commands with the prefix `/usr/bin/env`

```
$/usr/bin/env composer install (this runs OK)
$/usr/bin/env cd public (failed ---> /usr/bin/env: cd: No such file or directory)
```

I'm new to Linux and in my opinion, using `/usr/bin/env` is a weird way to write commands. I wonder why my second line didn't work (while some worked, like `mkdir` or `ls`)

The reason I cannot get rid of `/usr/bin/env` is that I'm using Capistrano and it keeps prepending the prefix. If there is a way to get rid of `/usr/bin/env`, that's even better.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve and why you are using `/usr/bin/env` in the first place.

Comment: As I noted in the bottom, I'm using Capistrano to run commands on server via SSH, and many commands were prepended with this `/usr/bin/env`

Comment: It's not much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run `env cd /path/to/directory` because there's no program called `cd` in your system. A process can change its working directory using a system call. In a shell you can use a builtin command `cd`. Calling it from `env` doesn't make any sense as it creates a new process that would exit just after changing its working directory. The new `env` process cannot change the working directory of the calling process in a standard way.

Comment: @Hoang Lam: See `type composer` and `type cd`.